# Netbeans 7.x: Maven creates my project in the wrong directory

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, directory, installation

I cannot get **Netbeans 7.3.1** to create a **Maven Web Application** in the directory I specify.

```
OS: Windows 7 x64
NetBeans: 7.3.1
Maven: 3.0.4/3.0.5
```

I am using the **NetBeans GUI** and its internal **Maven 3.0.5** for creating that type of project. It always creates the project in the **root** of my **E:**\ drive, regardless of which folder I specify.

Here's an example: After I click the 'finish' button after having provided all the needed parameters to create the project:

```
>     cd E:\Dev\Java\Test; JAVA_HOME=E:\\Apps\\Dev\\jdk6u23 "M2_HOME=E:\\Apps (x86)\\Dev\\apachemaven\\apache-maven-3.0.4"
> "\"E:\\Apps
> (x86)\\Dev\\apachemaven\\apache-maven-3.0.4\\bin\\mvn.bat\""
> -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee6 -DarchetypeVersion=1.5 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=be.kdg -DartifactId=mavenproject22 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=be.kdg.mavenproject22 -Dbasedir=E:\\Dev\\Java\\Test -Darchetype.interactive=false --batch-mode archetype:generate Scanning for projects...
>                                                                         
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
> 
> <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom
> <<<
> 
> [archetype:generate] Generating project in Batch mode Archetype
> defined by properties
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype:
> webapp-javaee6:1.5
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parameter: groupId, Value: be.kdg 
Parameter: artifactId, Value: mavenproject22
Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT 
Parameter: package, Value: be.kdg.mavenproject22
Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: be/kdg/mavenproject22
Parameter: package, Value: be.kdg.mavenproject22
Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Parameter: groupId, Value: be.kdg 
Parameter: artifactId, Value: mavenproject22

project created from Archetype in dir: E:\mavenproject22
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
BUILD SUCCESS
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Total time: 1.643s Finished at: Sat Sep 21 20:01:57 CEST 2013 Final
> Memory: 8M/120M
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the 22nd time I tried creating a **Maven Web Application** project in a specified directory. NetBeans or Maven just won't listen and I don't know why this is happening.

If the basedir is *E:\Dev\Java\Test*, then why does it create my project in **E:**\ root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and I have tried this: "Check registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor and see if you have an Autorun key set there. I deleted mine and got it to work."   But I don't have autorun option . Any other solution for this plz!! .

Comment: This solved another NetBeans path problem I had. I didn't verify it yet but I am now pretty sure this is the root cause. If anyone can verify this, let me know. Thanks a million Johan! It took me three years to solve this problem!

Comment: This was the most annoying thing I have ever encountered. Nothing else worked. I had originally changed this so my cmd prompt would default to my D drive rather than my C drive.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me..

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.4 RC1 (Build 201309162201)
Java: 1.7.0_40; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.0-b56
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_40-b43
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
```

Output

```
cd D:\temp\NetBeansProjects; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_25" cmd /c "\"\"D:\\tools\\NetBeans7.4 RC1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee6 -DarchetypeVersion=1.5 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=sample.webapp -DartifactId=mavenproject24 -Dversion=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=sample.webapp.mavenproject24 -Dbasedir=D:\\temp\\NetBeansProjects -Darchetype.interactive=false -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"D:\\tools\\NetBeans7.4 RC1\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" --batch-mode archetype:generate\"\""
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>

<<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<

--- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
Generating project in Batch mode
Archetype defined by properties
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: webapp-javaee6:1.5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parameter: groupId, Value: sample.webapp
Parameter: artifactId, Value: mavenproject24
Parameter: version, Value: 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Parameter: package, Value: sample.webapp.mavenproject24
Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: sample/webapp/mavenproject24
Parameter: package, Value: sample.webapp.mavenproject24
Parameter: version, Value: 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Parameter: groupId, Value: sample.webapp
Parameter: artifactId, Value: mavenproject24
project created from Archetype in dir: D:\temp\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject24
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.943s
Finished at: Sun Sep 22 17:41:23 CEST 2013
Final Memory: 9M/241M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I suspect this being a bug with NetBeans 7.3.1. If you could kindly set up a test environment for that particular case? I was unaware of a NetBeans 7.4, but I see it is still in RC.

Comment: very unlikely, if this were a general issue with 7.3.1 it would have been filed as issue long ago. Does your E:\Dev\Java\Test directory exist? with the exact case?

Comment: Of course it does. I also read of some unfixed bug reports of 7.3.1 with similar behavior of bugs that have been fixed in 7.2.1 but re-occurred in 7.3.1. This is not a general issue - it is a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also works for me in 7.3.1

```
cd D:\Program Files (x86); "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_25" "\"D:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.3.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\"" -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee6 -DarchetypeVersion=1.5 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=mavenproject25 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.mycompany.mavenproject25 "-Dbasedir=D:\\Program Files (x86)" -Darchetype.interactive=false --batch-mode archetype:generate
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>

<<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<

[archetype:generate]
Generating project in Batch mode
Archetype defined by properties
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: webapp-javaee6:1.5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parameter: groupId, Value: com.mycompany
Parameter: artifactId, Value: mavenproject25
Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Parameter: package, Value: com.mycompany.mavenproject25
Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: com/mycompany/mavenproject25
Parameter: package, Value: com.mycompany.mavenproject25
Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Parameter: groupId, Value: com.mycompany
Parameter: artifactId, Value: mavenproject25
project created from Archetype in dir: D:\Program Files (x86)\mavenproject25
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.603s
Finished at: Thu Sep 26 23:57:13 CEST 2013
Final Memory: 13M/304M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I do not deem it very useful if everyone keeps posting 'for me it works' answers. I would like more troubleshooting answers.